# Powershell Regex Grouping from Select-String

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

I am scraping a web request response to pull information held within html code which repeats a few times so using select-string rather than match. My code looks like

```
$regexname = '\(\w{0,11}).{1,10}\'
$energenie.RawContent | select-string $regexname -AllMatches | % {$_.matches}
```

The return looks something like:

```
Groups : {<h2 class="ener">TV </h2>, TV}
Success : True
Captures : {<h2 class="ener">TV </h2>}
Index : 1822
Length : 33
Value : <h2 class="ener">TV </h2>

Groups : {<h2 class="ener">PS3 </h2>, PS3}
Success : True
Captures : {<h2 class="ener">PS3 </h2>}
Index : 1864
Length : 33
Value : <h2 class="ener">PS3 </h2>
```

I can't workout a way to grab the second element of groups e.g. TV or PS3 as:

`$energenie.RawContent | select-string $regexname -AllMatches | % {$_.matches.groups}`

Gives a strange output

Paul

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

**$energenie.RawContent | select-string $regexname -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }**

Comment: Thanks @rohitgupta I now realised I was making an assumption and asked the wrong question. I was wanting a piped ForEach-Object to either return a list of unique names, TV, PS3 or repeat the same value representing a count of matches TV, TV due to the Index. I've now used your example to capture the groups collection but step through every other element to get TV, PS3

Comment: @PaulB, I only edited it.  Buxmaniak actually posted this.  If this is not rubbish then you should upvote it.  And if  it solves your problem then you should tick it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the second item in a collection, use the array index operator: `[n]` where `n` is the index from which you want a value.

For each entry in `Matches`, you want the second entry in the `Groups` property so that would be:

```
$MyMatches = $energenie.RawContent | select-string $regexname -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches}
$SecondGroups = $MyMatches | % {$_.Groups[1]}
```

To get just the captured value, use the `Value` property:

```
$MyMatches | % { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

Comment: Thanks @MathiasRJessen as described above I realised from the answers is that what I wanted was every other element in the array

Comment: Every second match in $_.Matches or every second Group in each match?

Comment: Every second in groups. The code ended up as:

`$socketname = ($energenie.RawContent | select-string $regexname -AllMatches).matches`

`For ($i = 1; $i -lt ($socketname.groups).count; $i+=2) {

  Write-Output "$(($socketname.groups[$i].Value).Trim())"

}`